# Embedding Sways in Newsfeed?

Tags: sharepoint-online, embedded

I would like my SharePoint site users to be able to contribute their Sways to the Newsfeed app on a page by embedding the Sway so it can be viewed in the News Feed.

I know I can accomplish this using Discussion Board, but the presentation offered by News feed would allow the presentations to be right on the page where Discussion Board it would be clicking away. I also know I can post a link to a Sway in Newsfeed, but following that link would take the user away from my page which I don't want to do.

Is it possible to activate the embed feature that exists in a Discussion Board post in Newsfeed?  Seems like this is all it would need.